# Facebook app - can't retrieve users Facebook post information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have a very important and urgent problem with our Facebook app. The app is a complicated competition where one of the "questions" is the possibility for the users to post a message to their wall. The app will then count how many LIKES this particular wall posts have gotten.

So the users can enter a high score page where - for each user - the app will try go get the post info through a call like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]?access_token=[TOKEN_ID]
```

The big problem is that for most users then the app cannot get the post-information. We just get a "Unsupported get request". For some users it works fine. I would say that around 20% is working ok.

Some things to remember

- We ask for permission to READ_STREAM
- We have the users Facebook ID and the Facebook Post ID (for all
  entries - also those returning a "Unsupported.....") so all seems fine on our side.

So what might be the problem here? We understand that there could be numerous issues like users blocking apps, private/public settings etc. - but it just seems very odd that around 80% of the users will have these settings. Have we forgotten anything or done anything wrong?

If you have any insights on the above please let's hear them. We are getting pretty desperate as we have an inoperative highscore running at the moment and we wonder if it ever will work properly.

Code Example:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$postid.'?access_token='.$accessToken), true);
```

Where `$postid` is the id of the FB post.*

Comment: What access token are you using when retrieving the post information?

Comment: Please see above. I edited the original questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you are doing mostly everything right but require just one minor change, you are requesting post information with URI

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$postid.'?access_token='.$accessToken
```

The `$accessToken` you are utilizing here is an [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/).

So instead of App Access Token you need to use the User's Access Token to get his/her private posts. Most probably when you would have retrieved the Post information from User the Access Token you might have used would have been User's Access Token.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Could you perhaps be a litte more specific? I haven't exchanged access tokens between the users who wrote the posts and the app - so now I'm in a situation where I have a bunch of post-id's and I need to retrieve info about ALL of them. Is that even possible at this point? Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Jan Sorry, but this is a dead end. I tried creating same scenario and I also reached the same dead end on getting the post that is not public using App Access Token. You could send Users notification or app request so that you can do the storage of User's Extended Access Token for use later.

Comment: Thanks for the try and your replies. Much appreciated - all though we didn't reach a solution.